# How to set `Duplicate Tab On Right` to a shortcut in Dopus?

Tags: directoryopus

I'm trying to set `Duplicate Tab On Right` to a shortcut, `Shift-Alt-RightArrow`, however, I couldn't figure out how to set it. I guess it is possible. Does anybody knows how?

Answer (score 0):

Add a hotkey that runs the command `Go CURRENT OPENINDUAL`.